# HAVING and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, having

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows

> For each continent show the continent and number of countries with populations of at least 10 million

The world table looks like this:

```
 World (name, continent, area, population, gdp)
```

My query (which is not returning the correct result):

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(name)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING sum(population) >= 10000000
```

Query returning the correct result:

```
SELECT continent, COUNT(name)
FROM world
WHERE population >= 10000000
GROUP BY continent
```

Can someone tell me why my query is wrong?

Comment: The question is about countries, not continents, so you need to do the filtering *before* aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about countries, not continents, so you need to do the filtering before aggregation.

Your version of the query is answering:

> How many countries are in continents whose population is greater than 10,000,000?

The question is:

> How many countries in each continent have a population greater than 10,000,000?

These are different questions.  I also realize that for non-fluent English speakers, the difference may not be obvious at first read.

Comment: When I remove the `HAVING sum(population) >= 10000000` and execute the result of the query is same as that of keeping `HAVING sum(population) >= 10000000` and executing.Does it implies that there is no effect of `HAVING sum(population) >= 10000000`

Comment: That simply means that all continents (with countries) have a population of at least 10,000,000.

Comment: My english seems to be terrible.Thanks for your patience though :)

Answer (score 0):

The *WHERE* clause filters rows **before the aggregation**, the *HAVING* clause filters **after the aggregation.**